# escape loop using an error from async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

let me explain what I mean using an example

```
async function async_function(){
    await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,3000));
    throw 'task completed'
}

async function do_something_meanwhile() {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
}

(async ()=>{

    try {
        async_function(); //this returns an error after a while
        while (...)
            await do_something_meanwhile();
    } catch (err) { console.log('exited with error:',err) }

    console.log('moving on');
})();
```

I'm trying to run an async function and after it is complete immediately terminate the loop,
the best way I could think of (without any time delay) was to send an error

but it gives this error instead of `moving on` after it's done:

> ```
> node:internal/process/promises:246
>           triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
>           ^
>
> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing 
> inside of an async function without a catch block, 
> or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with
> .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "task 
> completed".] {
>   code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
> }
> ```

is there a way around this or a better to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Change `async_function(); ` to `await async_function();`

Comment: @banyudu - The OP seems to want to allow the work of the function to overlap with the loop under it. `await` would do them in series instead.

Comment: @banyudu that would defeat the purpose

Comment: @cakelover using `await Promise.all` should be ok for parallel execution. I'll try to give a demo in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle rejection by setting an error variable that you can check in the loop:

```
try {
    let error;
    async_function()
    .catch(err => error = err);
    while (...) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        await do_something_meanwhile();
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('exited with error:',err)
}
```

If you need to proactively tell `do_something_meanwhile` to terminate as well, you could use an [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) and pass its `signal` to `do_something_meanwhile`.

```
try {
    let error;
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;
    async_function()
    .catch(err => {
        error = err;
        controller.abort();
    });
    while (...) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        await do_something_meanwhile(signal);
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('exited with error:',err)
}
```

I think if I were doing that, I might subclass `AbortController` so I can put the error in it:

```
class AbortContollerWithError extends AbortController {
    abort(error) {
        this.error = error;
        super.abort();
    }
}
```

then:

```
try {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;
    async_function()
    .catch(err => {
        controller.abort(err);
    });
    while (...) {
        if (signal.aborted) {
            throw controller.error;
        }
        await do_something_meanwhile(signal);
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('exited with error:',err)
}
```

...or something along those lines.

You asked how you'd use the signal in `do_something_meanwhile`, and suggested in a comment that you're really using a timer in it. That's where the signal's `abort` event comes in handy, you can use that to settle the promise early:

```
async function do_something_meanwhile(signal) {
    let cancelError = {};
    try {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const timer = setTimeout(resolve, 500);
            signal.addEventListener("abort", () => {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                cancelError = new Error();
                reject(cancelError);
            });
        });
        console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    } catch (error) {
        if (error === cancelError) {
            // Probably do nothing
        } else {
            // Something else went wrong, re-throw
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, I've never used  `AbortController` and everything I could find online is for `fetch()` but none the less I can't understand how `do_something_meanwhile(signal)` would be different from `do_something_meanwhile(error)` , could you write the `do_something_meanwhile()` function as well so I can get a better idea?

Comment: @cakelover - `fetch` can use an `AbortController`, but that's just one use. `AbortController` is for any situation where you have a process you need to proactively abort. The way you'd use its `AbortSignal` in `do_something_meanwhile` depends entirely on what `do_something_meanwhile` does. If it uses something that, like `fetch`, supports `AbortSignal`, it would pass it on to that. And/or it could listen for the `abort` event on the signal, and/or check its `aborted` flag (like the `while` loop does). Depends on what the function does and uses.

Comment: @cakelover *"I can't understand how `do_something_meanwhile(signal)` would be different from `do_something_meanwhile(error)`"* The difference is A) `signal` will be an `AbortSignal`, while `error` would just be `undefined` (since we *just* checked it), and B) `AbortSignal` instances have that event and `aborted` flag.

Comment: ah so it would be like the `signal` variable would be changing even after we pass it in `do_something_meanwhile(signal)`?

Comment: @cakelover - `signal` won't change, but its `aborted` flag (`signal.aborted`) would change if `async_function` rejects its promise. So if `do_something_meanwhile` does something somewhat lengthy, it might be handy to have it stop proactively. If it doesn't, then just the check in the `while` loop is probably sufficient.

Comment: I understand but how would that terminate the `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));` inside the `do_something_meanwhile`? wouldn't it still cause some amount of delay? where as I'm looking to make it instantaneous

Comment: @cakelover - That's where using the event on the signal comes in. I assumed the timer thing was just a placeholder, but if it's literally what you're using, then you'd use the signal's event to fulfill or reject the promise ahead of time. I've updated the answer to show what that would look like.

Comment: @cakelover - In the updated answer, if you don't see `error === cancelError` in the last code block, hit refresh. I wasn't happy with the earlier version. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Promise.all can run `async_function` and `do_something_meanwhile` in parallel mode.

While Promise/A doesn't have a cancel method, you can define a `stopFlag`, and check it in `do_something_meanwhile` function and the while loop.

```js
let stopFlag = false

async function async_function() {
  await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, 3000));
  throw 'task completed'
}

async function do_something_meanwhile() {
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
  if (!stopFlag) {
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
}

(async()=>{
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      async_function().catch((err) => {
        stopFlag = true
        throw err
      }), // this returns an error after a while
      (async () => {
        while (!stopFlag)
          await do_something_meanwhile();
      })()
    ])
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('exited with error:', err) 
  }

  console.log('moving on');
})();
```

Comment: nice attempt but if I increase `500` to `10000` you'll see there's a delay for the `do_something_meanwhile` to terminate where as I need it to terminate as soon as async_function() throws the error (btw I did not downvote you answer)

Comment: @cakelover If you'd like to cancel the `do_something_meanwhile` function as soon as possible, you may want to use `process.exit(0)` if there isn't other code waiting to run, or use [cancelable-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cancelable-promise)